General Approach for: m boys and n girls are in a queue, then find no. of ways in which no. of boys ahead of every girl is greater than no. of girls
I already know that 3 similar questions of this type are already asked on this platform, but I have a little different query and that is for a general case considering this sort of question.
Link to one of those questions :
Three boys and two girls stand in a queue. p, that the number of boys ahead of every girl is at least one more than number of girls ahead of her.
My Question is :

what if there are m boys and n girls standing in a queue and then I want to find the
number of ways in which the number of boys ahead of every girl is at
least one more than the number of girls ahead of her. (m>n)

Original Question :

Three boys and two girls stand in a queue. The probability, that the
number of boys ahead of every girl is at least one more than the
number of girls ahead of her, is?
{source: JEE-Adv 2014} {Ans - 1/2}

I found the answer to the original question by forming cases of the condition and that is what I usually will do for this sort of question when the question has small values and I don't have any good idea to find this using combinatorics.
When m = n, I find the question similar to Catalan number but not really sure about it and I am not really sure about the constraints that I gave ( I said m>n *).
I hope someone finds a general way to solve this question and also help with the constraints of the question that I gave.
Thank you in Advance!

In general, the probability is $(m+1-n)/(m+1)$. This the ties-allowed version of Bertrand's ballot theorem.
